# Saber se um app está aberto através de um BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Tenho um `BroadcastReceiver` que exibe uma notificação ao usuário!

Mas caso o usuário esteja com o app aberto (com a tela ativa), gostaria de cancelar a notificação!

Existe alguma forma de descobrir se o app está aberto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Costumo usar esse método para lançar ou não uma notificação para o usuário.
Vai retornar true se o app estiver fechado e falso caso aberto. Aplique ele no seu Receiver.

```
    /**
 * Method checks if the app is in background or not
 */
public static boolean isAppIsInBackground(Context context) {
    boolean isInBackground = true;
    ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> runningProcesses = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
        for (ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo processInfo : runningProcesses) {
            if (processInfo.importance == ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND) {
                for (String activeProcess : processInfo.pkgList) {
                    if (activeProcess.equals(context.getPackageName())) {
                        isInBackground = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> taskInfo = am.getRunningTasks(1);
        ComponentName componentInfo = taskInfo.get(0).topActivity;
        if (componentInfo.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName())) {
            isInBackground = false;
        }
    }

    return isInBackground;
}
```